# Convolution of probability mass functions (3 non-parametric distributions)

Tags: probability, statistics

I am familiar with the convolution of probability mass function when it involves two random variables, but I get a little confused when there's a third one.

I have to find the probability mass function of Z = W + X + Y where W, X and Y are independent random variables and with the given table:

[image]

I am not sure about the general formula to solve this. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Let U=W+X and then Z=U+Y..

Comment: @herbsteinberg has handed you the outline. If you can convolve the densities of $W$ and $X$ to get the density of $W + X$, convolve that new density with the one you have for $Y$ to get what you want. Works for sums of even more than three!

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is an exercise in theoretical methods of getting
the distributions of sums of discrete random variables, I would
do this by simulation. It seems that the sum of your three random
variables is reasonably well-approximated by a normal distribution.
[One analytic method might be to multiply the three moment generating
functions, where the distribution of the sum can be found
by collecting similar terms.]

Simulation in R. With a million iterations you can
expect about 2 or 3 significant digits of accuracy.

```
set.seed(2021)
m = 10^6
x1 = sample(0:4, m, rep=T, p=0:4)
summary(x1); var(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.000   3.000   2.999   4.000   4.000 
[1] 1.001328  # aprx Var(x1)

x2 = sample(0:4, m, rep=T, p=c(2,3,3,2,0))
summary(x2); var(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    0.0     1.0     1.0     1.5     2.0     3.0 
[1] 1.049731

x3 = sample(0:4, m, rep=T, p=4:0)
summary(x3); var(x3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   0.000   1.000   1.001   2.000   3.000 
[1] 1.001272

s = x1 + x2 + x3
summary(s);  sd(s);  var(s)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0     4.0     6.0     5.5     7.0    10.0 
[1] 1.748697   # aprx SD(S)
[1] 3.057941   # aprx Var(S)
```

Simulated distribution table:

```
table(s)/m
s
       1        2        3        4        5 
0.008076 0.034235 0.084840 0.161267 0.211413 
       6        7        8        9       10 
0.211874 0.161167 0.084805 0.034200 0.008123
```

Notice in particular, $P(S=1) = P(X_1=1, X_2=0, X_3=0)$
$=(.1)(.2)(.8) = 0.008.$

```
hist(s, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.3), br=(-.5:12.5), col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, mean(s), sd(s)), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I will definitely note this down for my future homework about convolutions! But my prof wants me to prove this manually first before using R that's why I need a general formula to work with